# jQuery live dialogclose seems to cause multiple fires

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table generated by an AJAX call on document ready.  On clicking the elements in the table, a dialog box is opened where the element can be edited.

When the save button is clicked, the changes are saved back and the dialog closes fine, but I want to trigger a re-load of the AJAX that generates the table.

After quite a few edits, here's the current code.  I added a console log to get more info.

When the modal dialog is closed with the X close icon (not saved) the console log reports as expected.  If I click save in the modal, which calls another set of code, the console log reports the same thing 100's of times in a few seconds.  A refresh is all that stops it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#elementView").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        resizable: false,
        close: function () {

            $("#elementholder").html('Loading elements...<br /><br />');

            var jobid = <?= $_GET[jobID]; ?>

            console.log("performing post to get elements list for jobID " + jobid);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_listelements.php",
                data: "jobid=" + jobid,

                success: function (msg) {

                    // alert ("success");

                    if (msg == 'error') {
                        $("#elementholder").html('<font color="red"><b>Error</b></font>');
                    } else {
                        $("#elementholder").html(msg);
                    }

                } // complete AJAX success          
            }); // complete AJAX
        } // complete close function                                                        
    }); // complete modal


    // detect row click on elements page to open modal

    tr = $('#elementtable').find('tr');

    // 1.7.1:  live is deprecated in 1.9, would need to change on jQuery ON 
    tr.live('click', function (event) {

        elementID = $(this).find("td.thisID span").html();

        // modal content loaded from mdl_element.php using ID
        $('#elementView').load('mdl_elementview.php?elementID=' + elementID).dialog('open');

    });

});
```

Comment: not sure, but the ajaxComplete function doesn't belong there, because it is called after success, so after completion. Remove the ajaxComplete line. Note that .live() is deprecated!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I'll edit the post as per your recommendation.  I'm not sure where to place #elementholder now though (I'm a jQuery beginner!)

Comment: $("#elementholder").html('<font color=\"red\"><b>Error</b></font>'); and  $("#elementholder").html(msg);

Comment: Thanks, @Garyte - I've applied your suggestions.  Still the same problem but I do feel it's getting closer!

Comment: does the success get fired?

Comment: Yes; if I remove the jobid= alert, and add alert("success") immediately after success: function(msg){  ... the alert appears - but again, repeatedly.

Comment: Use a current jQuery-Version! `.live()` is deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9! - current version is [1.10.2](http://jquery.com)

Comment: @cog1, do you place this code multiple times in your html? try a 'return false;' after ' }); // complete AJAX'

Comment: @Garytje yes, the ajax element is called by more than one condition (I know I should sort that out... one thing at a time!).  I added return false; as you suggested, same problem occurred.  I even added it in the same position to the other occurrences but that didn't appear to help either!

Comment: But the problem you had is solved right? The html now fills with the correct message in stead of loading elements...?

Comment: No, sorry!  Same issue.  I've gone through and removed some other ajaxComplete lines, which I had in other instances of the same code, testing as I went to make sure the rest of the functionality stayed.  But this issue remains; I'll edit to post the current code, showing where the alert is now.

Comment: Ha!  Fixed it.  There's a PHP file loaded - mdl_elementview.php.  THAT had the extra ajaxComplete function in place.

Thank you @Garytje - you solved the problem by pointing that out and asking if the code was duplicated anyway; it took ages to find the specific section!

Answer (score 0):

An extra ajaxComplete function, inside a separate PHP file that's loaded by an AJAX call on this page, was causing it.  Advice from @Garytja to remove the ajaxComplete functions led to lots more testing, and suggestions that the code is repeated elsewhere led to the other file.

Works well now.

Comment: happy to be at your service!